# Optimize custom Object Property in Array with Javascript

Tags: javascript

Look at the 3 lines of code within this Javascript function. Assume that `y` will always be a *String*:

```
function example(x, y) {
    var s = {};
    s[y]  = x;
    return s;
}
```

Bearing in mind the following:

1. Without wrapping it further within a function
2. Without using `;`

Is it possible to condense the 3 lines of code into one?

Comment: Learning "code tricks" like this is a waste of time. If this is an interview question then for shame.

Comment: No, if a good answer is found it will actually be used in a project.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, with a little ugly code:

```
function example(x, y, s) {
  return (s = {})[y] = x, s;
}
```

The extra parameter `s` is not passed into the function, it's only there to be declared as a variable, so you don't need the extra line `var s;`. (If you don't declare it locally it becomes a global variable, which is bad practice.)

The value of the assignment `s = {}` is what's assigned, so you can make the assignment and then continue using the value in the expression.

The comma operator returns the last value, e.g. `(1,2)` returns the value `2`. That way you can add `, s` to the expression to make it return `s`.

#### Edit:

Another variation is using `s` as a variable in a `for` loop, and exit out of the loop:

```
function example(x, y) {
  for(var s = {}; s[y] = x, true;) return s;
}
```

Comment: Almost what I need. Very sweet! Unfortunately only those 3 lines within the function can be edited, passing 's' as an extra parameter is not possible. nevermind - your 2nd edit covers it.

Comment: @michael: Incidentally I just added a variation that uses `for` to delare the variable instead of having it as a parameter. It's still pretty ugly code, though.

Comment: Although I agree that a `for` statement meets the definition of a single statement for code-golf purposes, surely a `for` statement that in itself includes all three statements from the original question *plus* an extra 'true' is still not really an improvement.

Comment: Guffa - question, item 2: *Without using `;`*

Comment: @nnnnnn: Of course it's not an improvement, the original code is as good as it gets, it's just different.

Comment: @RobG: I take that to mean that you should not just cram the three statements onto a single line. Any single line solution would still end with a semicolon, unless you use some extra construct just to get rid of that one too.

Answer (score 1):

Is using `function` cheating? :)

```
function example(x, y) {
    return new function () { this[y] = x; };
}
```

Answer (score 1):

There is always evil eval:

```
function example(x, y) {
  return eval('({' + y + ':"' + x + '"})');
}
```

But I still don't see the point in this.

Comment: I was just about to do this myself. Silly question needs silly answer.